# Unable to compare date column in query formula when a range is used

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a formula that fetches data from multiple sheets. except the dates the other stuff works fine.

[Here is the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W0aLMpYvudxAGaDJm2HxMdN8U4lEdvCZla8Kj9IjvIs/edit#gid=0)

```
       =QUERY({
iferror(indirect(if(E1,"January!A:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""});
iferror(indirect(if(F1,"February!A:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""});
iferror(indirect(if(G1,"March!A:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""});
iferror(indirect(if(H1,"April!A:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""});
iferror(indirect(if(I1,"May!A:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""});
iferror(indirect(if(J1,"June!A:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""});
iferror(indirect(if(E3,"July!A:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""});
iferror(indirect(if(F3,"August!A:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""});
iferror(indirect(if(G3,"September!A:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""});
iferror(indirect(if(H3,"October!A:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""});
iferror(indirect(if(I3,"November!A:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""});
iferror(indirect(if(J1,"December!A:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""})}, "Select *  where Col2 <>'' AND Col1 = date '2020-01-02'" )
```

The January sheet has data, but still I am not able to display query result.

**UPDATE:** Some of the monthly sheets may or may not exists, even if true is selected in E1 Fq G1 etc

The february sheet is missing, if true is slected in F1, it should not error, So I am using indirect formula with iferror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this formulas:

```
=QUERY({
iferror(indirect(if(E1,"January!A2:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""});
iferror(indirect(if(F1,"February!A2:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""});
iferror(indirect(if(G1,"March!A2:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""});
iferror(indirect(if(H1,"April!A2:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""});
iferror(indirect(if(I1,"May!A2:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""});
iferror(indirect(if(J1,"June!A2:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""});
iferror(indirect(if(E3,"July!A2:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""});
iferror(indirect(if(F3,"August!A2:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""});
iferror(indirect(if(G3,"September!A2:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""});
iferror(indirect(if(H3,"October!A2:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""});
iferror(indirect(if(I3,"November!A2:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""});
iferror(indirect(if(J1,"December!A2:I","")),{"","","","","","","","",""})}, "Select *  where Col2 <>'' AND (Col1 = date '2020-01-02' or Col1 = "&value("2020-01-02") &")" )
```

Improvements to original formula:

1. Use data without headers for query. Query formulas cannot handle multiple formats at once.
2. Use `or` condition in query statement. Query transforms all values into numbers or to dates, depending on what values are more frequent. Thus you need to check both: `Select *  where Col2 <>'' AND (Col1 = date '2020-01-02' or Col1 = 43832)`

Comment: Super explanation. Thanks Max

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't know why sometimes it can't compare dates. Also I don't understand why I can't nest iferror within query and work on ranges with curly brackets.

Finally I decided to make a small table where I check if sheet exists (independent on your table with tick boxes).

If both conditions are met, Query uses the range. If not, it uses a row of blank cells.

My solution is here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rBOpxZx3IztLKkWPKyUDf-GMW1HqcENHDRDKQfm7_oQ/edit?usp=sharing

The formula I use looks like this:

```
 =QUERY({
if(E1+M2=2,{January!A1:I},{"","","","","","","","",""});
if(F1+M3=2,{Febryary!A1:I},{"","","","","","","","",""});
if(G1+M4=2,{March!A1:I},{"","","","","","","","",""});
if(H1+M5=2,{April!A1:I},{"","","","","","","","",""});
if(I1+M6=2,{May!A1:I},{"","","","","","","","",""});
if(J1+M7=2,{June!A1:I},{"","","","","","","","",""});
if(E3+M8=2,{July!A1:I},{"","","","","","","","",""});
if(F3+M9=2,{August!A1:I},{"","","","","","","","",""});
if(G3+M10=2,{September!A1:I},{"","","","","","","","",""});
if(H3+M11=2,{October!A1:I},{"","","","","","","","",""});
if(I3+M12=2,{November!A1:I},{"","","","","","","","",""});
if(J3+M13=2,{December!A1:I},{"","","","","","","","",""})}, "Select *  where Col1 < date '2020-12-02' and Col1 is not null" )
```

Column M contains test if sheet exists.

Comment: Not to assume that the February, March etc sheets are present. When they are not present, the non use of indirect will cause errror. So there is a need for indirect. This solution doesnt help. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate if you could solve this with use of indirect.

Comment: Please find my update. I don't know what exaclty causes the problem with data format. I only found that if you use range with { } instead normal range it works o.k. I can look further. I will if there's a solution that allows to exlude existing months from the query.

Comment: Still doesnt work, could you share me the working link sheet to your answer please.

Comment: You stated___I see you have a table where you put TRUE when sheet exists and FALSE when it does not.____

Its not correct, the sheet may or maynot exist, the true indicates results must be displayed, false indicate results must not be displayed.

Comment: I totally rewrote my answer. Please see if it works for you

Comment: This is awesome. I really appreciate your time and help. God bless you!